# SparkOnHBase throws ERROR “had a not serializable result: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result”

Tags: apache-spark, serialization, hbase

It throws error when build spark like this

```
config("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer")
```

and the error is

```
ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 12) had a not serializable result: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result.Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result
```

If i change JavaSerializer to KryoSerilizer，it works.

But in my application, it must use "JavaSerilizer", because of service.

Answer (score 1):

You can't serialise HBase Result using JavaSerializer. You can convert result to (Array[Byte],java.util.List[(Array[Byte], Array[Byte], Array[Byte])]) with below code.

```
    val it = result.listCells().iterator()
    val list = new util.ArrayList[(Array[Byte], Array[Byte], Array[Byte])]()

    while (it.hasNext) {
      val kv: Cell = it.next()
      list.add((CellUtil.cloneFamily(kv), CellUtil.cloneQualifier(kv), CellUtil.cloneValue(kv)))
    }

    (result.getRow(),list)
```

Comment: why not JavaSerializer？